# Deeply nested directives with a parent controller/directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

This is somewhat of a contrived example of nested directives, but hopefully you'll understand what I'm trying to achieve:

http://plnkr.co/edit/FLNzNcfdCc8dHut1Bgsq

At any rate, let's take an example: say we have some type of custom form object, which contains sections, subsections, and categories:

```
<my-custom-form form="form"></my-custom-form>
```

Now, you'll see there's a directive hierarchy here, where each directive requires the one above it:

```
<my-custom-form>
   <section>
      <subsection>
         <category></category>
      </subsection>
   <section>
<my-custom-form>
```

What's the best way for my `<category>` directive to talk with `<my-custom-form>` directive? Per the Plunker, you can see that I'm channeling a message all the way up through each controller, but this seems dirty and unsustainable, and I end up copying a lot of code (e.g. you'll note the `isCategoryVisible(category)` method was copied 4 times just so the `<category>` could talk to `<my-custom-form>`!

Is there a regimented Angular pattern I'm missing here? Should I just provide the same controller to all my directives instead of trying to put them in this hierarchy? Is Angular expecting me to do what I've done here, and pass messages up on the controller? Any opportunity to use `$emit()` and `$on()`?

TLDR: What's the best way to get grandchild directives to talk with their grandparents? `<category>` ---> `</my-custom-form>`? I've very familiar with services, but I don't want this service to have to track state, the Form object itself contains all the state.

Comment: you can just add grandparent directive as required, and use it controller directly

Comment: @Grundy That's an option, but I lose the nested inheritance, as every sub-directive is simply a child of `<my-custom-form>`, which I guess is fine, just wondering if this is _the_ correct approach / best practice.

Comment: can you explain why you need `isCategoryVisible` on every level?

Comment: @Grundy This is a contrived example - let's say the isCategoryVisible function doesn't just return a static property, but actually runs logic to determine if the category should be displayed. I think the answer here in general is what you mentioned, that I just inherit from the grandparent directive wherever I need it

`require: [^myCustomForm, ^subsection]`

Comment: i think it can depends from concrete goal, sometimes better a bit fix structure.